# How can I modify the color of breakpoints and their surrounding background in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been able to modify the gutter background as seen in the picture below with:

```
"editorGutter.background":"#282828"
```

[image]

But I would like to modify just the color of the area where the breakpoint is- the area before the line numbers.

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Do you mean just the breakpoint dot? Or the area surrounding the dot except the area surrounding the line number? Or both? Or the whole area containing the dot and line number?

Comment: @user I mean just the area where the breakpoint is drawn, from the line number to the left, not including the area containing the line number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of there being a way to change the background of only the section of the gutter that surrounds the breakpoint icon. I know you can change the entire gutter's background, and you can change the colour of normal breakpoints and disabled breakpoints (conditional breakpoints share the same colour customization point with regular breakpoints). The settings you can change are as follows:

```json
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "debugIcon.breakpointDisabledForeground": "#ffff00",
    "debugIcon.breakpointForeground": "#ff00ff",
    "editorGutter.background": "#ff0000"
}
```